# Encoding High Cardinality variables

Tags: python, cardinality

I am really struggling in dealing with high cardinality on the dataset I am working on ...

I am using a dataset that has a lot of categorical variables and most of them have a very high cardinality.

The dataset contains nearly 2M of financial transactions.
Most of the variables are categorical, and some of them have a very high cardinality.  Example:

'ZIP code' has 985 unique values
'street' has 999 unique values
'merchant' has 693 unique values
'city' has 906 unique values
'latitude' has 983 unique values
'longitude' has 983 unique values
'state' has 51 values
'cc-num' has 999 values
....

I have read a lot about high cardinality using online resources, but still can't get my head around ..  I get very confused.

I have read that 'Leave-one-out encoder' which is similar to target encoding is a good technique for dealing with high cardinality. I thought it was good as it doesn't create any extra column.  But this type of encoding brings an output with floats as it calculates the mean of the target variables for all the records containing the same value for the categorical feature variable in question.

The problem is that after the encoding, I would need to do Feature Selection.  And when using MUTUAL INFORMATION as a feature selection technique, I get an error saying that variables shouldn't be 'float type'.  But this is what the 'leave one out' encoding technique.

Other techniques I have see are 'Weight of Evidence', which think is going to give floats as output.

I have also seen hash-encoding works well with high-cardinality,  but think it is complicated and don't have much time before submission.  So my idea was to use 'Leave One Out' encoder. Then do feature selection using Mutual Information and finally use Bagging, Random Forest and Boosting Algorithms to create the models.

Seeing the problem 'Leave One Out' encoding technique is giving me ...  The other option is to use ' Frequency or Count Encoding'. But don't know if it is the right technique ...

My questions are:

1). Encoding variables has to be done before Feature Selection. Am I right?
2). Is there a way I can do 'leave one out encoding' and be able to use the encoded variables using for feature selection and in the models.
3). Would frequency encoding be an appropriate technique ?

Thank you!
Eva

Comment: All of these questions really depend on the question you are addressing. Why are you modelling the data?

Comment: I am modelling the data in order to create a model to detect credit card fraud.

Comment: I have just read that CatBoost is an encoding technique that might work for high cardinality.  As it is It is intended to overcome target leakage problems inherent in LOO.   So, would using that technique and then use CatBoost for feature selection be a good idea?  Thank you!

Comment: Reducing the cardinality of a dataset is as much an art as a science, the lowest hanging fruit I can propose is to look through Kaggle forums / competition entries predicting credit card fraud. This type of problem is very common, it's then up to you to decide whether a similar technique can be applied to your data. E.g. https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud/code

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with high cardinality categorical variables is a common challenge in machine learning. I'll try to answer your questions and provide some additional suggestions:

> Encoding variables has to be done before Feature Selection. Am I right?

1. Yes, you're right that encoding variables should be done before feature selection. You need to convert categorical variables into numerical ones before you can compute mutual information or any other feature selection metric.

> Is there a way I can do 'leave one out encoding' and be able to use the encoded variables using for feature selection and in the models.

2. You can use the encoded variables for feature selection and modeling. The error message you're getting might be because of the data type of the target variable. Make sure that it's in the right format for mutual information computation. Another option is to use a different feature selection technique that works with floating-point variables, such as correlation-based feature selection or Lasso regression.

> Would frequency encoding be an appropriate technique ?

3. Frequency encoding is a simple technique that can work well in some cases, but it has its limitations. It replaces each category with its frequency in the dataset, which can be problematic if two categories have the same frequency. One option is to use target encoding or leave-one-out encoding with regularization, which can prevent overfitting and handle rare categories more effectively.

Here are a few more suggestions that might be helpful:

- Group rare categories into a single "other" category. If a category appears only a few times in the dataset, it might not provide enough information to the model and can lead to overfitting. Grouping such categories can simplify the problem and reduce the dimensionality of the feature space.
- Use embedding techniques to map categorical variables into a lower-dimensional continuous space. This can be done using methods such as Word2Vec, GloVe, or FastText. These methods can capture complex relationships between categories and reduce the dimensionality of the feature space.
- Try different encoding techniques and see which one works best for your problem. There's no one-size-fits-all solution, so it's important to experiment with different methods and compare their performance.
- Consider using dimensionality reduction techniques, such as PCA or t-SNE, to reduce the dimensionality of the feature space. These techniques can help you identify which features are most important for the model and can improve its performance.

##### Resources

---

- [An Overview of Categorical Encoding Methods](https://www.kaggle.com/code/arashnic/an-overview-of-categorical-encoding-methods)
- [11 Categorical Encoders and Benchmark](https://www.kaggle.com/code/subinium/11-categorical-encoders-and-benchmark)